# Replace comma and dot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, euro

I have a Column with data like 3.4500,00 EUR.
Now I want to compare this with another column having float numbers like 4000.00.
How do I take this string, remove the EUR and replace comma with decimal and then convert into float to compare?

Comment: you can use [.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 13):

You can use regular expressions to make your conditions general that would work in *all* cases:

```
# Make example dataframe for showing answer
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':['3.4500,00 EUR', '88.782,21 DOLLAR']})

              Value
0     3.4500,00 EUR
1  88.782,21 DOLLAR
```

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regular expression:

```
df['Value'].str.replace('[A-Za-z]', '').str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)

0    34500.00
1    88782.21
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Explanation:

- `str.replace('[A-Za-z\.]', '')` removes all alphabetic characters and dots.
- `str.replace(',', '.')` replaces the comma for a dot
- `astype(float)` converts it from object (string) type to float

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

mock data:

```
         amount     amount2
0   3.4500,00EUR    4000
1   3.600,00EUR     500
```

use apply() then convert the data type to float

```
data['amount'] = data['amount'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('EUR', '')).apply(lambda x: x.replace('.', '')).apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', '.')).astype('float')
```

result:

```
    amount    amount2
0   34500.0     4000
1   3600.0      500
```